# Third-party payment. What's this?

Tags: android, paypal

Sorry for my English.
I need to integrate PayPal to Android app. In this app are buyers and sellers. I need that buyers can purchase goods at the seller using the application. 
README:
"Until features such as third-party, parallel, and chained payments are available, you can use MPL"
Second and third I understand.
What is third-party payment? Please explain to me.

Comment: Third-party means an external source. In your case it means PayPal application or the PayPal website in a webview.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases the developer (app owner) is sending or receiving money using their own account.  A 3rd party payment would be where the application sends/receives money between two different accounts that do not belong to the developer directly.

For example, you might build an app that allows anybody to send money to anybody else using PayPal.  So then if I logged in to your app to send money to my buddy, that would be a 3rd party payment.  I'm using your app to send money from my account to another account...neither account is actually yours, though.

Comment: As I understand I need to use the old library MPL? In my app, buyers shall make payments directly to the seller.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend it anyway as the new stuff just isn't nearly as mature and time-tested.